# Fill polygon with pattern instead of color Geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, gis, geopandas

I'm trying to fill polygons with some pattern instead of a color (due to I must print the project B&W). So far I've only managed to fill them with a grayscale but I would like to take the pattern approach if is there any way to do so.

A piece of my code is the following:

```
if info['max']=='catarro':
    poly = Polygon(shape, facecolor = "#DDDDDD", alpha = alpha, linewidtt = 0.01)
    plt.gca().add_patch(poly)
```

This if statement is inside a for loop which runs over info and shape. If some fact of info matches with a string, I just color a poly and add it as a patch over a shapefile.

I also would like to add this pattern in some manner to a legend.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A recent commit to [geopandas](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas) allows for passing a `hatch` argument to the `plot` method on a GeoDataFrame, so if you installed from the latest source, and you have a `GeoDataFrame` named `gdf`, you can do:

```
gdf.plot(facecolor="#DDDDDD", hatch="//")
```

You could then plot any subset you want, based on matching some attribute. It is a little unclear to me from your example how your data are structured, but something like:

```
gdf[gdf["key"] == value1].plot(facecolor="#DDDDDD", hatch="//")
gdf[gdf["key"] == value2].plot(facecolor="#DDDDDD", hatch="o")
```

and so on.

The most recent `geopandas` available on pip or conda does not have this functionality. You can still pass the `hatch` keyword to `matplotlib.patches.Polygon` (which seems to be what you are using in your example) to control the styling, which would in your example above just be:

```
 poly = Polygon(shape, facecolor="#DDDDDD", alpha=alpha, linewidth=0.01, hatch="\\")
```

A fuller demo of plotting hatches is available in the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hatch_demo.html).

To add a legend, you can keep a list of plotted polygons, and associated labels, and pass those to `legend`. So, inside your loop above, something like:

```
polys.append(poly)
labels.append(search_str)
```

And then, outside your loop:

```
ax.legend(polys, labels)
```